# Timestamp on one sheet from updated cell on another VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with upto 31 sheets,(named (01),(02) etc, Each with the same format as per the screenshot below 
[image: Workbook1]

I wish to use the following code which I have found(with help from this forum :) ) to place a timestamp in a mirror file (WorkBook2) that will work out the difference from when column B and Column C in workbook 1 is changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("B:B, C:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then 'add Columns that will be changed to BA:BA and BB:BB
        'add error control
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        'don't do anything until you know something has to be done
        Dim r As Range
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Intersect(Range("B:B, C:C"), Target) 'i know this would only work on the same sheet
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()   'Need to get this section to populate workbook2
        Next r
    End If
safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image: Workbook2]

I know people have asked similar questions and im sorry if this is a duplicate but I really am lost on trying to get this to work.

Edit - Workbook two sheets are named in the same way with just a "t" after ie (01t), (02t) etc

Comment: You need to explain a bit more. Do you mean if B2 on sheet 01 of workbook 1 is changed you want the date and time put in B2 of sheet 01t of workbook 2, and similarly for column C? You probably need to use the Workbook_SheetChange event to avoid having to repeat same code in all 31 sheets.

Comment: Hi SJR, Thats Exatly what i mean, i also need it to work column E, F,H,I,K,L etc  and if the cell change is on Cell B2 on sheet 02 then place the timestamp in B2 on Sheet 02t etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The code needs to go in the ThisWorkbook module of workbook 1 and you need to add the name of workbook 2.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range

On Error GoTo safe_exit
Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each r In Target
    Select Case r.Column
        Case 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12 'b c e f h i k l
            Workbooks("name of workbook2").Sheets(Sh.Name & "t").Range(r.Address).Value = Now()
    End Select
Next r

safe_exit:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR, I have tried the suggested code and it looks like the Sh.Name part is not working, If i place a Breakpoint on the End Select the r.Address is populated but the Sh.Name is not.

Comment: I managed to get this to work, I ended up decalring a variable PS as a string and passing the Sh.Name to it. Now just working on updating the cells on Workbook2 while the file remains closed. Thank You for your Help SJR ! :)

Comment: Glad it worked. `Sheets(Cstr(Sh.Name & "t"))` might work too.